# Constrain input to a few different strings

Tags: postgresql, constraint

Hi I can't seem to get a constraint working the way I expect in postgreSQL.
From within pgadmin I execute the following SQL query.

```
-- Check: "TypeCheck"

-- ALTER TABLE "ComLog" DROP CONSTRAINT "TypeCheck";

ALTER TABLE "ComLog"
  ADD CONSTRAINT "TypeCheck" CHECK ("Type" SIMILAR TO 'email|post|IRL|minutes');
COMMENT ON CONSTRAINT "TypeCheck" ON "ComLog" IS 'One of email|post|IRL|minutes';
```

When executed this is converted to.

```
-- Check: "TypeCheck"

-- ALTER TABLE "ComLog" DROP CONSTRAINT "TypeCheck";

ALTER TABLE "ComLog"
  ADD CONSTRAINT "TypeCheck" CHECK ("Type" ~ similar_escape('email|post|IRL|minutes'::text, NULL::text));
COMMENT ON CONSTRAINT "TypeCheck" ON "ComLog" IS 'One of email|post|IRL|minutes';
```

I expect this to limit my input for the Types column to one of email post IRL or minutes. However when entering table data this constraint fails when i enter one of these types.
The Types column is of character type.
Does anyone know how to fix this.
Thanks.

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding something, is there a reason it wouldn't be much easier to read to do `CHECK (type in ('email','post','IRL','minutes')` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change your constraint to

```
CHECK (type IN ('email','post','IRL','minutes'))
```

This will be converted by the parser into:

```
CHECK (type = ANY( ARRAY['email','post','IRL','minutes']))
```

That should do what you are looking at.

However I have to wonder if it wouldn't be better to do this:

```
CREATE TABLE comlog_types (
     type text
);
```

And then add a foreign key to enforce the constraint.  This would make it easier to add types in the future.

Comment: Thanks, that's solved it perfectly. I might look into changing to the foreign key method in the future.

Comment: Yeah, it does work nicely. But you may also want to check out PostgreSQL's [enum data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-enum.html).